# Child dialog doesn't show up in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Hi, I'm trying to make simple GUI application using PyQt5, Python 3.4 and Windows 7.

Below code works properly.

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog


class MainWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.popup_dlg = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.show()

        self.popup_dlg = ChildWnd()


class ChildWnd(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWnd()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Two windows are created. One is main window and the other is child window(popup window). **But what I want is to make child window's default location is centered of main window**.

So I've modified the code like this.

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog


class MainWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.popup_dlg = None
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.show()

        self.popup_dlg = ChildWnd(self)  # make instance with parent window argument.


class ChildWnd(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent_wnd):
        super().__init__()
        self.setParent(parent_wnd)  # set child window's parent
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWnd()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But this code makes problem. Child window doesn't show up. Only main window(=parent window) shows. In Qt's QDialog's manual, I found this.

> but if it has a parent, its default location is centered on top of the
>   parent's top-level widget (if it is not top-level itself).

This is why I added the **setParent()**.

What should I do?

Please help me!!

Comment: Did you try passing the parent object as parameter to the super constructor of your QDialog? -> super().__init__(parent_wnd)

Comment: @Daniele Pantaleone, I added parent object to child window's super().__init__() and remove self.setParent() .  It works!  Works exactly what I want!!. Thank Daniele Pantaleone. You saved my whole day XD

Comment: @Daniele Pantaleone, Oh by the way, I want to adopt your answer. But I can't adopt the comment. Can you please rewrite as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qdialog.html) calling `setParent` will just change the ownership of the `QDialog` widget. If you want the `QDialog` widget to be centered within it's parent, you need to pass the parent widget instance to the super constructor of your `QDialog`:

```
class ChildWnd(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent_wnd):
        super().__init__(parent_wnd)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.show()
```

Comment: This is what I exactly want! Thank you again!!